# Scala future return based on first future result

Tags: scala, filter, akka, future, for-comprehension

I have a Scala future that calls an api and returns future, if the result isn't correct, then another api call will be submitted with first future's result and returned as future.

This is what I have so far.

```
val fut1 = Future(queryFirst)
val fut2 = fut1 map {
  case y if y.isInstanceOf[NoResult] => Future(queryAgainWithFut1Result)
  case x => x
}
```

But if I access fut2 result, it gives something like this:

```
scala.concurrent.Await.result(fut2, 5 seconds)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
fut2: Any = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@61ab71c2
```

Is there a way that I can choose to return fut2 if fut1 result is not accurate?

**Edit:**
Second future has to use first future to continue api call. This is what I have so far.

```
val fut1 = Future("queryFirst")
val fut2 = fut1 flatMap {
  case y if y.isInstanceOf[Int] => Future("queryAgainWithResult(y)")
  case x => Future(x)
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `recoverWith`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `filter` the first `Future` to cause it to fail when its contained result doesn't match what you want, then use `recoverWith` to recover the value to another `Future`.

```
Future(queryFirst)
    .filter(result => /* logic that returns true if result is correct */)
    .recoverWith { case NonFatal(e) => Future(querySecond) }
```

If `queryFirst` is successful and makes it through the `filter`, then it's result will be returned (wrapped in the `Future`).

If `queryFirst` is successful and does not have a correct value according to the `filter` *or* simply fails, then the result of `Future(querySecond)` will be returned, success or fail.

---

**Edit:** In light of the new information from the OP, if you need the result of the incorrect first `Future`, then you don't really have a choice but to use `flatMap`.

```
Future(queryFirst).flatMap {
    case result if(/* failed condition */) => Future(querySecond(result))
    case result => Future.successful(result)
}
```

Comment: great answer deleting mine

Comment: Actually, second future has to use first future's result to continue the api call. You method won't work unless I can access first future's result.

Comment: Yah. I found out after testing it. Sorry~~

Comment: @angelokh you should just open another question that accurately describes what you want and get rid of your update. m-z's answer is perfectly valid and interesting to the SO community based on your original question.